# Comparing hashes in RSpec that contain BigDecimal

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec

I am using RSpec (3.x) to test an object that acts similar to a calculator. The object puts the results into a hash. But I cannot get the hash to match correctly in my tests. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
class ObjectUnderTest

  def calculate(a, b)
    value = a.to_d / b
    {
      value: value
    {
  end

end
```

The test looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe ObjectUnderTest do

   it "calculates the product of two values" do
     o = ObjectUnderTest.new
     expect(o.calculate(1, 3)).to eql({value: 0.333})
   end
end
```

The problem is that 0.333 is a float and the actual value being included in the hash is a BigDecimal. If I change the line in the test to say something like:

```
expect(o.calculate(1, 3)).to eql({value: 0.333.to_d(3)})
```

... the test still fails A) because the precision is different, and B) in my actual code, I have several key-value pairs and I don't want to have to call k.to_d(some_precision) on all of the comparison hashes to get it to pass.

Is there a way to compare the values using something like a_value_with some range do I don't have to hard-code an exact number in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating point numbers are inexact (even to the point that `(0.1 + 0.2) == 0.3` returns false), so you have to use matchers that allow for values *near* to your expected value rather than equal.  RSpec's `be_within(x).of(y)` (and its alias, `a_value_within(x).of(y)`) is designed for matching floating point numbers.  RSpec 3 also supports composable matchers and the `match` matcher [allows you to match nested hash/array data structures](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/01/new-in-rspec-3-composable-matchers/#match) by putting matchers in place of values, so you can do this:

```
expect(o.calculate(1, 3)).to match(value: a_value_within(0.001).of(0.333))
```

Comment: @MikeFarmer If it is what you were looking for, that means he provided the perfect answer to your question. Mark the answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using `eq` instead of `eql`

checkout rspec various [equality matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers)

Comment: Thanks, I double checked using eql and eq and it doesn't make a difference.